# What is the proper term for a function where domain and codomain coincide?

Tags: functions, terminology, definition

> What is the proper term for a function where domain and codomain coincide?

E.g. in programming languages a function f : Int => Int or f : Double => Double.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have a function $f:S\to S$, that is $f$ is a function from $S$ with image (range) in $S$. Such a function is called an <del>endomorphism</del> endofunction (endo comes from the greek or latin word for "within"). Sometimes people use the term codomain to mean the image (range) of a function. If $S$ is finite and the image of $f$ is the whole set $S$, then $f$ is a bijection. If $S$ is infinite, the situation is somewhat more complicated.

Edit: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: That is not correct. A *morphism* which maps a mathematical object $S$ to itself is called an endomorphism. A morphism is a function which preserves structure. A function is just a map - it doesn't care about structure.

Comment: Uh,oh, let's scratch that

Comment: How about _endofunction_?

Comment: Why of course, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism#Endofunctions_in_mathematics

Comment: This is the first time I heard of *endofunction* ever!

Comment: I've never heard of it either. Although reading the article I am led to say (for the first time ever) [citation-needed]!...

Comment: @user1729: A rigorous definition of a _morphism_ is found in category theory. A morphism need not even be a function. Answering "endomorphism (in $Set$)" is correct.

Comment: @sdcvvc: I don't know much category theory, but is it not true that in a concrete category it *is* a function. I mean, a linear transformation, or a group or ring homomorphism, is just a function with additional properties...

Comment: @user1729: As I said, in category Set, a morphism $X \to Y$ is (any) function from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Oh right, I thought all you were saying is that a morphism is a function in Set. Clearly I cannot read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

A function $f:S\to S$ can be called an endomorphism in **Set**, and one doesn't have to worry about the structure-preservation that is implied by *-morphism* because sets have no additional structure to preserve.

However, it depends on the context: if I want to talk about *any* function $f:V\to V$, $V$ being a vector space, and I were to use the term *endomorphism*, it would be understood that $f$ is a linear transformation, because the morphisms in $K$-**Vect** are linear transformations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a widespread term for that which is acceptable in all contexts, but a function $X\to X$ is sometimes called a *function on $X$* or an *operator on $X$* or a *unary operation on $X$*.